# From bootstrap 3.3.7 to bootstrap 4.1.3

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I read everywhere that bootstrap 4.1 is comparable with bootstrap 3 but
when I migrate project to higher version a lot of thinks stop working for example this cookie consent

```
    @{
    Layout = "";
}

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>*@

@if (true)
{
    <nav id="cookieConsent" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="alert">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cookieConsent .navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle cookie consent banner</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <p class="navbar-text">
                    Use this space to summarize your privacy and cookie use policy.
                </p>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Learn More</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-cookie-string="@cookieString">Accept</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        (function () {
            document.querySelector("#cookieConsent button[data-cookie-string]").addEventListener("click", function (el) {
                document.cookie = el.target.dataset.cookieString;
                document.querySelector("#cookieConsent").classList.add("hidden");
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
}
```

Is there any way to migrate to newer version of bootstrap and not crashing old style?

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that v3 and 4 are compatible. They are not. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: ok. Is there any tutorial chow to migrate or maybe you can help to rebuild this cookieconsent ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that you can use independently or combined, depending on the amount of effort you're comfortable with.

You can read [the official migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) that covers all major changes.

Or, if you know what your cookie consent is supposed to look like, you can cycle through a process of:

1. Find a part of UI that looks broken
2. Inspect the broken element and it's classes
3. Rename individual classes that changed between v3 and v4, breaking the element
4. Repeat step 1

There are also [guides that can summarize major changes](https://designmodo.com/migrate-bootstrap-4/).